# Delphi RESTClient parsing JSON

Tags: json, rest, delphi, delphi-10.2-tokyo

I use TRESTClient, TRESTRequest, FRESTResponse and RESTResponseDataSetAdapter like in RESTDebugger (Delphi Tokyo) and it works fine but for one JSONValue the webservice send me some HTML mix and It do not display the right thing in my TFDMemTable.

I make the same test with [JSONViewer](http://edn.embarcadero.com/article/40882) and it make the same things

Is there a way to modify my JSONStream just before it start to parse my RestReponse ?

Why it don't display all my JSONString for dev_msg_attention_to_garage ?

```
{"id_commande":"15672","id_devis":"16347","status":"CONFIRM","res_codres":"IDG","nom_client":"TESTRDV","prenom_client":"toto","mail":"test@test.fr","tel_port":"0606060606","date_prise_rdv":"2017-09-25 09:25:43.281269","date_rdv":"2017-09-27","heure_rdv":"17:30-18:00","immatriculation":"EC620XP        ","type_prestation":"FREINAGE","famille":"Disques et plaquettes avant","type_mine":"","codmar":"PEUG","numord":"9938","marque":"PEUGEOT","marque_modele":"PEUGEOT 206 1.1 60CV","cnit":"MPE1002K6315","aaa_caliloca":null,"aaa_cape":null,"aaa_ccreditbail":null,"aaa_canton":null,"aaa_carrosserie":"BERLINE","aaa_carrosseriecg":"CI","aaa_catclient":null,"aaa_catclientvo":null,"aaa_catvendeur":null,"aaa_co2":"154","aaa_codifvin":"VF32AHFZE40061368","aaa_consexurb":"5.1","aaa_consmixte":"6.2","aaa_consurb":"8.2","aaa_couleurvehic":"MARRON","aaa_cstrvincg":null,"aaa_cylindree":"1124","aaa_date1ercir":"1998-10-15","aaa_datedcg":"2016-06-09","aaa_datedcgachat":null,"aaa_datedcgpr":null,"aaa_datedcgprachat":null,"aaa_depart":null,"aaa_departement":null,"aaa_depollution":"NON","aaa_empat":"245.0","aaa_empreintesol":null,"aaa_energie":"ESSENCE","aaa_gammemarche":null,"aaa_genrev":"VP","aaa_genrevcg":"VP","aaa_hauteur":"144","aaa_immatsiv":"EC620XP","aaa_largeur":"165","aaa_longueur":"384","aaa_marque":"PEUGEOT","aaa_marquecarros":"PEUGEOT","aaa_modeinject":"AUTR. CARBURATIONS","aaa_moderefroid":null,"aaa_modele":"206","aaa_modeleetude":"206","aaa_modeleprf":"206","aaa_mouvmt":null,"aaa_nserie":"40061368","aaa_nsiren":"000000000","aaa_nbcylind":"4","aaa_nbdecibels":null,"aaa_nbmain":null,"aaa_nbplass":"5","aaa_nbportes":"5","aaa_nbpropriet":null,"aaa_nbsoupape":"2","aaa_nbvitesse":"5","aaa_nbvolume":"2","aaa_nuancecouleur":null,"aaa_poidsvide":"910","aaa_prixvehic":"0","aaa_propulsion":"AVANT","aaa_ptr":"1405","aaa_ptrprf":"0192","aaa_puisch":"60","aaa_puisfisc":"5","aaa_rappuispoids":null,"aaa_regionadmin":null,"aaa_regmdecibels":null,"aaa_statutimmat":null,"aaa_temoincession":null,"aaa_tpboitevit":"MECANIQUE","aaa_transmiss":null,"aaa_turbocompr":"NON TURBO","aaa_type":"MPE1002K6315","aaa_typevincg":"2AHFZE","aaa_version":"XR\/PRESE","aaa_voiear":null,"aaa_voieav":null,"aaa_datews":"2017-06-16","aaa_3lnom":"fff","veh_codmar":null,"veh_numord":null,"veh_ktypenr":null,"aaa_pneus":"175\/65 R14 82 T, 165\/70 R13 79 T","aaa_typevarversprf":"2AHFZE","aaa_codemoteur":"HFZ","aaa_puiskw":"44","total_ht":"141.58","total_tva":"28.32","total_ttc":"169.90","total_ttc_max":"169.90","total_ttc_min":"169.90","dev_msg_attention_to_garage":"                                    \r\n                        \r\n                            \r\n                            attention\r\n                            \r\n                                ATTENTION Pour ce rendez-vous web nous avons identifi&eacute;\r\n                                plusieurs r&eacute;f&eacute;rences constructeur possible :<\/br\/>\r\n                                                                                                                                                                                         4249A5, <b>424995<\/b><br\/>     \r\n                                <br \/>Vous devez vous assurer que la\r\n                                r&eacute;f&eacute;rence indiqu&eacute;e correspond bien &agrave;\r\n                                celle mont&eacute;e sur le v&eacute;hicule du client <br \/>Le\r\n                                prix final &agrave; payer par le client doit &ecirc;tre de 169,90 \u20AC TTC                            \r\n                        \r\n                    \r\n\t\r\n \/ Le devis est en pi\u00E8ce budget","dev_msg_from_customer":"test message;\r\n","id":"15672","created_at":"2017-09-25 09:25:43.460187","updated_at":"2017-09-25 09:26:10.621387","coupon":[],"promotion_globale":[],"lignes_pieces":[{"codfam":"FDI","ssfam":"AV","designation_piece":"DISQUE DE FREIN AV PLEIN. DIAMETRE= 247X10MM","ref_constructeur":"424995","quantity":"2.00","remise":"0.00","pu":"0.00","taux_tva":null},{"codfam":"FPL","ssfam":"AV","designation_piece":"PLAQUETTES DE FREIN AV. MONTAGE BOSCH","ref_constructeur":"425320","quantity":"1.00","remise":"0.00","pu":"0.00","taux_tva":null}],"lignes_mo":[{"type_ligne":"FOI","designation_mo":"Forfait Isotech ","ref_operation_adauto":"FISOAD16990","quantity":"1.00","taux_horaire":"141.58","remise":null,"code_taux_horaire":null,"taux_tva":1.2,"montant_ht_ligne_apres_remise":141.58}],"deduction_rdv_en_ligne_ttc":"16.99","montant_a_regler_par_client":152.91,"pourcentage_remise_calculee_pieces":0,"total_remises":0,"total_ht_avant_remises":141.58,"pourcentage_remises":0,"pourcentage_remise_calculee_mo":0}
```

[image]

Comment: You're better off getting the service's vendor to fix their problem on the server side. This JSON data is malformed, and won't work anywhere.

Comment: I change the JSON File which was not good

Comment: Well, that changes everything. I'm confused. What exactly do you mean by "do not display the right thing"? What are you expecting to see? And what are you seeing instead? It is a very long string, and I'm not a bit surprised that it doesn't fit. Even pasting it in Notepad forces it to wrap, not being able to fit in a single line.

Comment: In fact it trunk my sting after rendez-vous web. It's why I want to modify it.

Comment: Looks like it's truncated around 255 characters. Why would you expect it to show any more? I wouldn't. It's not a production software - it's a debug tool. What exactly do you want to modify?

Comment: I want to get all string to parse and display what is important for me in my production software

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are being presented with a limitation of [Windows' `Tree View`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb773456(v=vs.85).aspx). From the documentation:

> Note that although the tree-view control allows any length string to be stored as item text, **only the first 260 characters are displayed**.

(Emphasis mine)

The quick answer is that since this control wraps Delphi's `TTreeView` implementation, it also inherits this limitation, and thus there's not too much you can do to overcome it, besides either implementing custom drawing or finding another control without this limitation.